# iReport: How can i display this layout?

Tags: layout, jasper-reports, ireport

Let say I used this query `Select customerName From tbCustomer`.
How can I display the result in this layout:

**CUSTOMER : customerA, customerB, customerC**

**NOT**

CUSTOMER

-customerA
-customerB
-customerC

Comment: What is your expectations (in layout) in case getting 20 or more customers?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done using columns and horizontal filling. That's the simplest solution. It should be easy for you to figure out how to do this if you know to define how many columns are in the report and set the "Print order" to Horizontal.

That would not have the commas that you show in your example, but it would be quite similar.

If you really want exactly what you have shown, then you could create a variable that appends each customer name to it as it iterates. In your simple example you would display this value in the Summary band (or Title or other band... but not the detail band).